# How to get click position from event in Avalonia.FuncUI

Tags: f#, avaloniaui

I'm trying to figure out how I can access the pointer position of a mouse click from the event click.
I've came up with something like

```
[...]
    type State = { coords: Point list }

    type Msg = Click of Point

    let update (msg: Msg) (state: State) : State =
        match msg with
        | Click p -> { state with coords = p::state.coords }


    let view (state: State) dispatch =
        Canvas.create [
             Canvas.onPointerPressed (fun event -> event.GetPosition ??? |> Click |> dispatch)
         ]
[...]
```

But that would require a handle to the control in place of *???*, to which i have no access.
Is there another way? Or a way the get a handle to the control?

Probably I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Source` Property on the `PointerPressedEventArgs` (or any other `RoutedEventArgs`) to obtain a reference to the firing Control.

```
let view (state: State) dispatch =
    Canvas.create [
         Canvas.background "white"
         Canvas.onPointerPressed (fun event -> event.GetPosition (event.Source :?> IVisual) |> Click |> dispatch)
         Canvas.children [
             for point in state.coords do
                 yield Ellipse.create [
                     Ellipse.width 5.0
                     Ellipse.height 5.0

                     Ellipse.fill "red"
                     Ellipse.top (point.Y - 2.5)
                     Ellipse.left (point.X - 2.5)
                 ]
         ]
    ]
```

Also note that you need to set the `Background` Property of a `Canvas` or you won't get `PointerPressed` events.

You also need to open the `Avalonia.Controls.Shapes` namespace if you want to use the Example above (because of `Ellipse`).